# JPA find entities where date is between start and end date that can be null using Criteria but null value must be initialized by MAX/MIN date

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

```
public class FileSpecification {

    public static Specification<FileEntity> getFilterdFiles(FilesFilterParams params) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(root.get("uploadDate"),
                    params.getUploadDateFrom() == null ? new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE) : params.getUploadDateFrom(),
                    params.getUploadDateTo() == null ? new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE) : params.getUploadDateTo()));

            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }
}
```

When `params.getUploadDateFrom()` or `params.getUploadDateFrom()` is `null` I want to use min date or max date instead.

But when the function is executed  I get the error:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: timestamp out of range: "292269055-12-02 21:47:04.192+05 BC"`.

Well `java.util.Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)` / `java.util.Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)` is too big date for my database. How can I get correct max/min value of date for postgres in my code?

I know that I can solve it by using multiple predicates `criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo`/`criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo`, but I want to know how to get correct max/min date.

Comment: I think it is not a good practice to use min/max values for dates in that case, simply add predicates to not consider your filter value if it is null, something like : `cb.and(cb.or((cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("uploadDate"), params.getUploadDateFrom())), (cb.isNull(params.getUploadDateFrom()))), cb.or((cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("uploadDate"), params.getUploadDateTo())),(b.isNull(params.getUploadDateTo()))))`.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is better that create constants for max and min values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/datatype-datetime.html) -

> PostgreSQL uses your operating system's underlying features to provide output time-zone support, and these systems usually contain information for only the time period 1902 through 2038

So, depending on your OS, I would consider simply defining constant values for 01-01-1902 (MIN) and 12-31-2038 (MAX)

Comment: You get link to 7.2 version of postgres but current is 14 version. But according this new documentation I found that min timestamp in postgres is 4713 BC and max is 1465001 AD. So now I can use constant "4713-1-1 BC" as min and "1465001-31-12 AD" as max to resolve my question

Comment: According to the [PostgreSQL 14 documentation about Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/datatype-datetime.html):

Min date: `"4713-1-1 BC"` = `new java.util.Date(-210866907600000L)`,

Max date: `"1465001-12-31 AD"` = `new java.util.Date(9224317997999999L)`